# Set units to X-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use this code for add units to axes, but x-axis looks horrible, numbers and units are overwritten. DO you have any idea how to solve it?

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d cm'))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d cm'))
```

[image]

Comment: you could try rotating the tick labels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to rotate the text of your ticks, try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker    

plt.plot(range(1000,11000,1000),range(10))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d cm'))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d cm'))

for txt in plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    txt.set_rotation(90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to specify the units used in *every single* tick, as it will be the same all along that particular axis. I'd suggest you to use the `xlabel()` and `ylabel()` methods, just like this example from matplotlib's documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/text_demo_fontdict.html